# How to use ommited library in java project

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have two libraries as dependencies in my project. Each of those two libraries has bunch of libraries as dependency. However there are two same named libraries with different version, and one of them as I can see in maven pom dependency hierarchy is ommited conflicting with same named one. When I run program program it uses elements of both "parent" libs, but it uses one of conflicting "child" libs whit which it tries to work with "parent" lib which should use other conflicting lib. So is it possible to have both conflicting libs used in project.

Thanks

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html Read how to exclude dependencies

Comment: Maybe my question was unclear, I don't wont to exclude anything, I wont use both!

Comment: I was offering as a suggestion, that you exclude the conflicting dependency of one of your libraries so it uses the non-conflicting dependency on the class path.

Comment: They don't conflict in a way of causing compile problem, they conflict when I look in dependency hierarchy of pom.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

You can use the Maven shade plugin to construct a shaded jar that contains the dependency with a different package hierarchy.

But the usual solution is to try to find a version of the library that works with all of the other stuff (not always possible, I know).